# Shadow animation not animating smoothly

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui

In SwiftUI, I have the following view as a skeleton loader. I'm trying to get the blurred overlay to smoothly animate in from the left side and out on the right side.

[Here's](https://media.giphy.com/media/v1.Y2lkPTc5MGI3NjExZ3VoaXQ1cmpwdHNuY253Y3hndmd5eGRrcGt5Nmp1ODdjdjY5Zjh4OCZlcD12MV9pbnRlcm5hbF9naWZfYnlfaWQmY3Q9Zw/r1BVW2JPaACtTAg1Vw/giphy.gif) what the below code produces (in light mode). As you can see, the beginning and end of the animation does not animate the overlay out smoothly, but rather inserts it without animation, then animates it most of the way, then removes it without animation.

```
struct SkeletonLoader: View {
    @State private var isAnimating: Bool = false
    let radius: CGFloat = 50
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color(CGColor(gray: 0, alpha: 0.15)))
                .overlay(
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color(CGColor(gray: 0, alpha: 0.6)))
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: 1000)
                        .blur(radius: radius)
                        .position(x: isAnimating ? geo.size.width + 180 + radius : -200 - radius)
                )
                .onAppear {
                    withAnimation(.easeIn(duration: 6.5).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)) {
                        isAnimating.toggle()
                    }
                }
        }
        .clipped()
        
    }
}
```

For some reason, removing `.clipped` fixes the smooth animation issue, but I need to clip my view so that the blur doesn't extend past my view.

I suspect this is a problem with SwiftUI not drawing the rectangle if its `position` is off the screen, even if there is still some blur left to animate.

How can I get this to animate smoothly from start to finish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`compositingGroup`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/compositinggroup()) on the rectangle to group it and its overlay together, so that the blur is applied, whether or not the overlay is clipped.

```
Rectangle()
    .fill(Color(CGColor(gray: 0, alpha: 0.15)))
    .overlay(
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color(CGColor(gray: 0, alpha: 0.6)))
            ...
    )
    .compositingGroup()
```

Answer (score 2):

As you say, the problem is probably because the off-screen part of the rectangle is not available to build the blur effect when the frame is clipped.

As a workaround, you can use a `Material` overlay to give the blur effect instead:

```swift
GeometryReader { geo in
    Color(CGColor(gray: 0, alpha: 0.15))
        .overlay(
            Color.black
                .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: 1000)
                .position(x: isAnimating ? geo.size.width + 180 + radius : -200 - radius)
        )
        .overlay {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(.regularMaterial)
        }
        .onAppear {
            withAnimation(.easeIn(duration: 6.5).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)) {
                isAnimating.toggle()
            }
        }
}
.clipped()
```